# Flexslider-white space on the right

Tags: html, css, flexslider

I inserted the flexslider with featured posts to my page, and it adds a huge space on the right, moving all the elements on the right to another line. I didn't change the CSS of it, any ideas why this could be happening?Thank you

Comment: You'll need to provide a link to the page, some code, or JSFiddle that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find `.flexslider{...}` in your custom-css, and add `float:left;`. Doing so will bring the, what looks like an upcoming event list, up next to it, to the right.